# How can I convert this cURL command to php code

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I can't seem to find any reference to the LH command this cURL command uses -- so I'm not entirely certain how to translate it to php

$ curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=mla; locale=fr-FR" http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842

Comment: Do you mean using PHP's `curl_*` functions?

Answer (score 0):

`curl -LH` is just two flags `L` and `H`.

See: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

`-L` = Location

`-H` = Header

In your code, you should either swap your flags to `-HL` or swap your argument values.